# Multimeter fails to measure current but voltage, resistance and continuity measurements work fine. Is the fuse blown?

Tags: multimeter, fuses

I am trying to measure the current of a pretty simple circuit consisting of an LED, resistor and 9V battery. As I said measuring the voltage, resistance, continuity works fine but the current measurement just shows 0 and the LED is very dim (I can't even see it with the lights on.) Is the fuse blown or is the whole multimeter fried?

Also when opening up the multimeter there are two fuses (10A and 0.2A both 5x20mm 250V.) I can't see if one of those is burned because it's covered by some white thing.

Comment: What model multimeter?

Comment: measure the fuse resistamce

Comment: @user28910 UNI-T UT33D+

Comment: @jsotola no way of doing that because i dont have a second multimeter

Comment: The lower-current fuse is **far more vulnerable** to blowing than that 10A fuse...if the 10A fuse blows, you generally know it from the sparks your probes see.

Comment: It is always handy to have more than one multimeter. Then you can use the other to measure the fuse. Or to measure the voltage drop over the multimeter that is in current mode.

Comment: 1) Multimeter fuses seem to be priced to make you think twice before you blow another one. 2) Also, if you're going to leave the leads plugged into the multimeter, make sure they're in the voltage sockets, not the current sockets (see 1).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're new to using a multimeter or not, but a common beginner mistake is assuming you can measure voltage and current the same way.

- For voltage, you measure "across" 2 points in the existing circuit.
- For current, you have to "insert" the meter in-line with an existing wire.

Taking a current measurement might require cutting a wire in your circuit and splicing the meter in between the cut points.

Voltage measurement:

```
A <-----probe1
|
| (wires, resistors, etc)
|
B <-----probe2
```

Current measurement:

```
A
|
| (wires, resistors, etc)
|
^probe1   (insert meter probes in-line with conductor)
vprobe2
|
B
```

Also, most meters have 3 jacks for the 2 probes. Voltage measurements use jacks 1 and 2, whereas current measurements use jacks 1 and 3. Some of the nicer meters will beep at you if you ask it to measure voltage when the probes are still connected to 1 and 3 (the actual labels on a meter vary, but a specific meter might say "common" for 1, "voltage" for 2, and "current" for 3).

Some meters will even make a helpful warning beep if you try to take a voltage measurement while a probe is still in the current jack.

Comment: Great suggestion! Edited just now.

Answer (score 2):

Many fuses are clear - you can see when the fuse wire inside them is broken.

The [user's manual for the UNI-T UT33D+](https://gotronik.pl/images/UT33+.pdf) multimeter you mentioned shows that it has ceramic tube fuses.  You can't see the fuse wire in ceramic fuses.

[image]

If you can't see the fuse wire, then you can do this:

1. Disassemble the meter and remove the fuses.  Note where each fuse belongs.
2. Reassemble the meter and use the ohms function to test the fuses.  A good fuse should register zero ohms.
3. Purchase replacement(s) for the bad fuse(s.)
4. Disassemble the meter and replace the fuses.
5. Reassemble the meter.

The fuses are only used in the ammeter function.  Other functions do not depend on them at all.

---

Measure current like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frJ7NF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

AM1 represents your multimeter in "ampere" mode.

Comment: Before you bother measuring a fuse, if it's got a transparent glass body just look at the innards -- often you get lucky and you can see that the fusing element is visibly burnt in two, with an obvious gap.  If that's the case -- congratulations, you don't need to bother checking it with an ohmmeter.

Comment: The question says the fuses have some "white thing" covering them.  I took that to mean that the fuse wire itself isn't visible.

Comment: Oops -- I missed that.  I'm going to let my comment stand for folks who have clear fuses.

Comment: @TimWescott - Hi, I see you have addressed this now, but also for future folks, [this review](https://lygte-info.dk/review/DMMUNI-T%20UT33D%2B%20UK.html) of the OP's multimeter model shows the [two fuses on the PCB having ceramic bodies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TteU.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

> *Is the fuse blown or is the whole multimeter fried?*

A simple test to establish whether the current measurement circuit is fried (and/or the fuse is open circuit) is this: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://themachineshop.uk/product/500v-ac-dc-manual-ranging-digital-multimeter/).

It works with most multi meters including my ancient radio shack model and saves you having to open the thing up: -

[image]

Forgive the glare --> it's reading 0.6 ohms. If it reads an open circuit or very high resistance then the fuse may be blown or the circuit may be fried and, that's when it's time to open up the meter.

Answer (score 0):

A burned fuse is the most probable cause, but other the burned components can be present to.

You can try to temporary short the fuse and check current measurement.

The 10 A fuse used for the 10 A range usually has a separate socket for the probe and the 0.2 A fuse is used for lower current ranges.